# Google translate taking out "please"

Tags: subjuntivo

I'm using Google Translate to translate some stuff for work, and I'm noticing it keeps taking out the word "please" and uses subjunctive instead. Is this appropriate or should I add the pleases back?

Examples:

"Please fill out the following form..." = "complete el siguiente formulario"

"If you have any questions, please contact..." = "si tiene alguna pregunta, comuníquese con..."

"Please note that..." = "Tenga en cuenta que.."

Any explanations would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Trevor, take my advice: do not use Google translate for work docs. Hire a professional (not just any) translator. It will pay off in the end. And you are asking at least three questions. As a pro translator myself, I am annoyed by this sort of thing. However, to show goodwill, bear in mind: to fill out a form in Spanish is **rellenar un formulario**.

Comment: Hi @Lambie, that is certainly not going to be possible where I work. In fact you are seeing here the extent of the resources that will be devoted to ensuring we get a decent translation for this project. I will continue to try to do a good job!

Comment: "Le rogamos rellenar el formulario que aparece a continuación" is the way to go. Le rogamos here stands for please, or is a way of showing politeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may seem odd to an Anglophone but Spanish norms of politeness are different. You do not usually need to say *por favor* as the same thing is provided by the use of the subjunctive. The nearest English equivalent is to start your request with "Would you mind .. " then you do not need please.

Comment: This is excellent, thank you so much!

Comment: You don't actually show how to use the subjunctive here or say would you mind.

Comment: @Lambie true, my focus was on the different norms of politeness which can come as a shock to the unwary rather than giving an answer about grammar (which would also have been valuable).

Comment: I don't think the subjunctive is often associated with being polite. It is more associated with some kind of modified imperative.

Comment: @Lambie another reason for not giving a mention of how to use the subjunctive is that I do not feel competent to do so so I refrained.